# Opencv can detect one out of two different size rectangles in the same paper

Tags: java, opencv

i am a newcomer in OpenCV and i am creating an OMR(Optical Mark Recognition) system in Java in order to detect the answers on a multiple choice paper sheet.I have created a form that consists of one big rectangle that is used for answering the questions by drawing the right circle, and one smaller rectangle that is for detecting a unique number that is the identity of the one answering.
Here is the image of the form:[image: Multiple choice sheet]

Now my programm is detecting the upper rectangle the AM one but cannot detect the bigger one. My image is passing though 6 stages 1st dilation,2nd gray, 3rd threshold,4th blur,5th canny and 6th adaptiveThreshold. Here you can see that

```
    dilated1 = new Mat(source1.size(), CV_8UC1);
    dilate(source1, dilated1, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, new Size(3, 3)));
    
    gray1 = new Mat(dilated1.size(), CV_8UC1);
    cvtColor(dilated1, gray1, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    thresh1 = new Mat(gray1.rows(), gray1.cols(), gray1.type());
    threshold(gray1, thresh1, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY + THRESH_OTSU );

    blur1 = new Mat(thresh1.size(), CV_8UC1);
    blur(gray1, blur1, new Size(5.,5.));

    canny1 = new Mat(blur1.size(), CV_8UC1);
    Canny(blur1, canny1,160, 80);

    adaptiveThresh1 = new Mat(canny1.rows(), gray1.cols(), gray1.type());
    adaptiveThreshold(canny1, adaptiveThresh1, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 11,2);
```

I am also using findContours like that

`findContours(adaptiveThresh1.clone(), contours1, hierarchy1, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);`

I have created two different java classes because there are other things to detect in the small rectangle and other on the bigger. The code above is what i am using in order to try detecting the bigger rectangle. I have tried many different numbers in all the steps and still nothing.

When i am using only the bigger rectangle in an image it works just fine, but in combination with the other one it cannot detect it. It's for my thesis and its really important for me. Any help is appreciated and whatever you want me to add in order to help you please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the **largest** contour and **second largest** contour.

Suggested stages:

- Convert image to Grayscale (as you did).
- Draw thick white rectangle around the image - making sure there is not black contour around the image.
- Apply threshold and convert to binary (as you did).
  The code I posted also inverse polarity, for the contours to be white.
- Find contours.
  Use `RETR_EXTERNAL` instead of `RETR_TREE`, because you don't need to find contours within contours.
- Iterate the contours, and find the one with the largest area, and the one with the second largest area.
  The contours with the largest area is the lower rectangle.
  The contours with the second largest area is the upper rectangle.

Here is a Python implementation (not JAVA, but close enough):

```python
import cv2

# Read input image
img = cv2.imread('image.png')

# Draw thick rectangle around the image - making sure there is not black contour around the image
cv2.rectangle(img, (0, 0), (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), (255, 255, 255), thickness = 5)

# Convert from BGR to Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply threshold on gray image - use automatic threshold algorithm (use THRESH_OTSU) and invert polarity.
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find contours
cnts, heir = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)


max_a = 0  # Maximum area
smax_a = 0 # Second maximum area

max_c = []  # Contour with maximum area
smax_c = [] # Contour with second maximum area (maximum excluding max_c)

# Iterate contours
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > max_a:    # If area is grater than maximum, second max = max, and max = area
        smax_a = max_a
        smax_c = max_c  # Second max contour gets maximum contour
        max_a = area
        max_c = c       # Maximum contour gets c
    elif area > smax_a: # If area is grater than second maximum, replace second maximum
        smax_a = area
        smax_c = c

#Get bounding rectangle of contour with maximum area, and mark it with green rectangle
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(max_c)
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), thickness = 2)

#Get bounding rectangle of contour with second maximum area, and mark it with blue rectangle
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(smax_c)
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), thickness = 2)

# Show result (for testing).
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: Great this is what i wanted, i would like to thank you for helping me out and i really appreciate it. Cheers to you! @Rotem